# What should the Authorization Server do when Resource Owner fails to authenticate him/herself in OAuth 2.0?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am developing an app and I am trying to save user data to a third-party service. The service allows me to access the users' resources via OAuth. I have finished implementing the OAuth flow and it works  as follow (when no error occurs):

1. I redirect the user to the authentication page of the service provider, providing the following parameters in the URL:
   `?redirect_uri=[my_redirect_uri]&client_id=[my_client_id]&response_type=code`
2. The user authenticate him/herself
3. The service redirect the user to the `redirect_uri` and pass me the authorization code in the URL parameter: `code=[authorization_code]`
4. I get the `access_token` from the `auth_code`
5. I can now access the user data

*You can see the diagram [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39820_01/doc.11121/gateway_docs/content/images/oauth/oauth_web_server_flow.png).*

I found out that for this particular service, when the user fails to authenticate him/herself (step #2), the Authorization Server immediately redirect the User-Agent to my `redirect_uri` and in the URL parameter I got `error=access_denied`.

I find this not a user-friendly experience because the user can make a typo or simply forget his/her credentials.

I checked the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). It seemed that there isn't any protocol on resource owner's authentication failure. I see in the RFC that there are protocols for Client authentication failure or Authorization failure. However, it is not stated how the Authorization Server should respond when it fails to authenticate the resource owner.

I did my own research by trying to login to Medium using Facebook OAuth. I see that when I fail to login, I am still in the Facebook authentication page, and Facebook notify me that my credentials is wrong. I can enter a wrong credentials **up to 3 times**, after which, the flow will break (the parameters in the URL associated with the OAuth disappears). When I enter the right credentials and deny Medium to access my profile, then, I was redirected to Medium with `error=access_denied`

Is what Facebook did the best practice? Is there a policy on the number of attempts allowable for resource owner authentication? What is the proper response when the Authorization Server fails to authenticate the resource owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response with `error=access_denied` actually complies with the OAuth2 specification. The section ([4.1.2.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1)) on error responses for the authorization endpoint when using the authorization code grant lists several possible error codes and says the following about the `access_denied`:

> access_denied
>     The resource owner **or authorization server denied the request**.

<sub>(emphasis is mine)</sub>

What does not feel right is treating invalid credentials immediately as an error and not letting the user retry the password input in order to safeguard occasional typos. However, that's left as the discretion of the authorization server, there's nothing (that I'm aware) in the specification that dictates when should the error be returned so not allowing the user to retry, although okay by the specification, is possibly bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth gives only a reccomandation on this case, it doesn't limit the number of attempts allowable for resource owner authentication.

If the authorization server observes multiple attempts to exchange an
authorization code for an access token, the authorization server SHOULD attempt to revoke all access tokens already granted based of the compromised authorization code.